# How to see the content of local storage of another website?

Tags: local-storage

As you know, modern browsers have local storage for every host. I mean that if go to www.stackoverflow.com, the local storage I'll see in the developer tools will be the one of www.stackoverflow.com. However, if I go to www.cnn.com, I'll see  total different information in local storage. My question is how can I watch the local storage for a host that I'm not in it. For example, let's say that I'm in www.cnn.com. How can I see the local storage of www.stackoverflow.com without navigating into it?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: You can't; that would be a **serious** security risk.

Answer (score 1):

For (hopefully) obvious security reasons, that's not a thing that you can do.

Comment: Why is that a security problem? E.g. I can see all of my cookies regardless of what site I'm on. How is localStorage different?

Comment: @melpomene - Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question, but it seems that the OP is asking "if I'm (the code for) site X, how can I see the local storage corresponding to site Y?".  That's quite different to what you're describing.

Comment: To me it looks like the "*I*" in OP's question consistently refers to OP themselves, i.e. a human user. That's why I voted to close the question as off-topic: It's application support for whatever browser OP is using.

Comment: @melpomene - Ah ok.  If that's the case, then I agree - this answer would be wrong, and the question would be somewhat off-topic.